# How to call method in other plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a eclipse plugin named mainPage ,and want to call a method in a plugin named Terminal.

I have already add Terminal to  Bundle-ClassPath and Require-Bundle,then I called the method in mainPage like this

```
new ShowToolStoreCommandHandler().execute(null);
```

This method is to open a window .
But i have a java.lang.NullPointerException when call this method.

I found the method getDefault() returns null when getting the instance of the Terminal in the Activator of Terminal.

So,how to call this method to open a window?

Comment: There is nothing special about calling methods in other plug-ins. But from the name of the class it probably expects to called as a Command Handler and will expect things to be set up appropriately.

Comment: In Terminal this method is called by command..By using  org.eclipse.ui.menus ,Terminal defines a button in org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar and when clicking the button,.command "Terminal.command.launchToolbar" will be using to call this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about calling methods in other plug-ins provided they are designed to be called that way.

The class you mention is probably a command handler so it will expect to be called from the command handler service with the environment set up correctly.

You can use the `IHandlerService` to execute command handlers:

```
String commandId = .... the command id 

IHandlerService handlerService = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IHandlerService.class);

handlerService.executeCommand(commandId, null);
```

This assumes the command handler doesn't need an `event` argument and doesn't require any command parameters. If it does the call will be more complex and requires more research.

The 'commandId' will probably be defined in the `plugin.xml` of the plug-in.